# cryptoapi for dummies

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi

Can some one point me to some books or online resources to help learn about the windows cryptoapi package?  I did find "Cryptography for Visual Basic" by Richard Bondi.  I'd be more interested in something aimed at C++ or the package in general.  The MDSN is overwhelming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple tutorial that could point you in the right direction. I hope it helps.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/EncryptionCryptoAPI.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that may be enough to get me started.  If anyone knows of a book I'd sure like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN can be overwhelming however there are some pieces of light. This page would provide you some context:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx

In any case, it really depends on what are you planning to do. If you're just using CryptoAPI to perform cryptographic operations you're fine with MSDN or just have a look to Wincrypt.h (there's a lot of info inside that header).

However, if you're panning to develop you own CSP (cryptographic service provider) with or without hardware you would need further information.

If you give me more details I can point you to the appropriate place (I did both things time ago).

Regards