# How to do asymmetric encryption and decryption in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, encryption, rsa

I got into trouble in Excel's VBA, as I need some asymmetric encryption.
I found that people are using System.Security.Cryptography, but as it's .NET library, I can't easily find my way thru (it can't be defined as object in VBA, so intellisense doesn't work).
often there are uses of `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider` , but I can't find any easily digestable text about using for example RSA (Which is I believe the best approach to asymmetric crypto in that library).

To make things even worse, we have both 32bit and 64bit office installed in our team.

Does anyone have experience with RSA implementation in VBA?

My plan is to create and save keypair, and then to use it for encryption and decryption of name&password stored in the file somewhere. I will have the whole keypair to edit the secret, users will only have public key to decrypt it.

Comment: You could do your own method using, matrix and vectors
https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_Lineal/Matriz_por_vector

this, if you need to crypt text
find a square matrix with inverse
separate the text as long as the dimension of your matrix
asign a value to each char, could use ascii,

Comment: Potentially this *might* be of interest where the CALG ID for RSA would be `CALG_RSA_KEYX`: http://satepadangajo.blogspot.com/2010/11/crypto-api.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448805/cryptoapi-for-dummies